# MVC 6 ASP.NET View(), Table for display a big Object with a numerous properties fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

Hello i am new to MVC Net 6, so far so go. I am using pagination, sort column and search box following this [Microsoft's Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0), plus i am using bootswatch to add stylesheet css to the views. The problem i have is the width of the html table for objects that have numerous properties fileds, is possible show the object in the browser shrinking the witdh of the table? i don't wannna lose pagination, for example a object with two properties displays good in a browser page [image: Small_Object_Display], but a object that have a bunch of fields display like this [image: Big_Object_Display_1] [image: Big_Object_Display_1], plus the object has textfields of 500 characters maximmum. Here is the code i am using.

**Object Model**

```
public class Order
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Code { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    public int CoinId { get; set; }
    public virtual Coin Coin { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int BuyerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Buyer Buyer { get; set; } = null!;

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string? Comments { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string? Field1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string? Field2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string? Field3 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string? Field4 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int AuditUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User AuditUser { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime AuditDateTime { get; set; }

    public bool AuditDelete { get; set; }
}
```

**Index**

```
@model PaginatedList<WebApplicationDailyPayments.Models.Database.Order>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Paises";
}

<h1>Ordenes</h1>

@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
{
    <h6 class="text-warning">@TempData["Message"]</h6>
}

<p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-area="" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Create">Crear Orden</a>
</p>

<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Encontrar por Nombre: <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary" /> |
            <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Index">Regresa a la Lista</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Proveedor
            </th>
            <th>
                Pais
            </th>
            <th>
                Categoria
            </th>
            <th>
                Codigo Orden
            </th>
            <th>
                Moneda
            </th>
            <th>
                Monto
            </th>
            <th>
                Fecha
            </th>
            <th>
                Fecha Tope
            </th>
            <th>
                Comprador
            </th>
            <th>
                Comentarios
            </th>
            <th>
                Campo 1
            </th>
            <th>
                Campo 2
            </th>
            <th>
                Campo 3
            </th>
            <th>
                Campo 4
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Provider.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.Acronym)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coin.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateEnd)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Buyer.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field1)
            </td>
            <td class ='text-nowrap'>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field2)
            </td>
            <td class='text-nowrap'>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field3)
            </td>
            <td class='text-nowrap'>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field4)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-warning" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Editar</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Eliminar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>

@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
}

<a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
   class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>
<a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
   class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>
```

**Controller Index Function**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
            ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_asc" : "";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

            var orders = _context.Orders.Where(u => u.AuditDelete == false).Select(all => all);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                orders = orders.Where(u => u.Code.Contains(searchString));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_asc":
                    orders = orders.OrderBy(u => u.Code);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 10;
            return View(await PaginatedList<Order>.CreateAsync(orders.Include(o => o.AuditUser).Include(o => o.Buyer).Include(o => o.Category).Include(o => o.Coin).Include(o => o.Country).Include(o => o.Provider).AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
        }
```

Comment: Well, that's the matter of display, so not really a C# question. If you want to display your object somewhat differently so that it fits on the page, you should also tell us how you would like to see it - just wrap the values inside the fields (then it's a matter of some css), or display them in separate rows (then you need to replace your table with divs) or ...?

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Thanks for the suggestion i swicth to divs after a research i could be able to make thje html page.

Answer (score 0):

Due the recommendation to use divs i could be able to format the page

**Index View use foreach to divs**

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Proveedor</b><br/>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Provider.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Pais</b><br/>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.Acronym)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Categoria</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Numero Orden</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Moneda</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coin.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Monto</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Fecha</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Fecha Tope</b><br/>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateEnd)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Comprador</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Buyer.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Campo 1</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field1)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Campo 2</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field2)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Campo 3</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field3)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <b>Campo 4</b><br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field4)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">
                <a class="btn btn-warning" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Editar</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Eliminar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<br />
}
```